# Saving nested objects with Rails, backbone.js, and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm using Rails, backbone.js (learning this now).  Let's say you have two models, Car and Engine.

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    if(this.get('engine') != undefined) this.engine = new Engine(this.get('engine'));
  }
}

var redCar = new Car({
      'color': 'red',
      // The controller nests the model
      'engine': {
         'horsepower': '350'
       }
    });


redCar.save()
```

What is the right way to send `engine_attributes` to the controller? (Car `accepts_nested_attributes_for :engine`, so it expects `engine_attributes`.) Do I override the Backbone `sync()`? Is there a better convention to follow for nested models?

Maybe I should not be returning nested models from the controller, or returning `engine_attributes` instead of `engine`?

On a side note, I am using the Rails `respond_with(@car, :include => :engine)` (same as `@car.to_json(:include => :engine)`. The fact that this api nests the engine attributes under `engine` but the model expects `engine_attributes` seems contradictory - I've never been sure how to reconcile this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would suggest to override toJSON on the backbone model.

```
toJSON: function(){

  json = {car : this.attributes};
  return _.extend(json, {engine_attributes: this.get("engine").toJSON());

}
```

toJSON is called within the sync method just before sending data to the backend.

Comment: Awesome, id suggest making your rails controller deal with backbones format, but this is much MUCH cleaner

Comment: I agree - I wish there was an option to do this in backbone.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: this.attributes should be cloned, or you'll soon be in a world of hurt :) Should be: _.clone(this.attributes)

Comment: Is this also the recommended solution for adding read-only props to the model? (e.g. special formats/calculated properties to be used in templates)

Comment: For templates? No I wouldn't use that. I personnally create accessors to compute/format the data. You could think of full fledge formatters but it can be difficult to manage for small projects.

Comment: As Emil Stenström pointed out, you should clone it first or use: _.extend({},json, some_attributes);

Comment: I think we must be careful with this approach, because this method is also used in the views, i.e. adding namespace will affect the way you're accessing attributes there.

Comment: I've added toJSON function to the backbone model where I've the nested attribute, but it is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Very helpful.  I was working with a similar situation, and this example did not work for me at first.  In my example I have a has_many / belongs_to relation.  For example a car has_many :tires.

The problem I encountered was that the tires_attributes needed to be nested INSIDE of the car json, not adjacent to it.  I ended up with something like this:

```
toJSON: function(){

  json = {car : this.attributes};
  json.car.tires_attributes = this.get('tires').toJSON();
  return json;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: there are two more options: 1) `wrap_parameters` which is a bit weird; 2) define attributes on the Car model as attr_accessible, make sure to include `tires_attributes` into the list, yes exactly!;

Answer (score 2):

I found this gem! Maybe help you.

http://blog.dtmtec.com.br/blog/2013/05/power-up-your-backbone-models-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you like to edit your answer, to add an excerpt of the article? That way, your answer will remain useful if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we've to do something with (or around) Backbone `sync` or with rails backend, because the problem in communication between two. Overriding `toJSON()` method might lead to unexpected results, because this is general purpose method and others parts of application might rely on, for example views.

Possibly quick solution:

```
redCar.save({}, {
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({car: redCar.toJSON(), engines_attributes: redCar.get('engines').toJSON()})
});
```