# Backbone Model.save doesn't wrap model state to nested object

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone Model.save doesn't wrap model state to nested object. Is it normal?

Typical scenario for Rails is something like this params[:product]. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was answered previously: [Saving nested objects with Rails, backbone.js, and accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226067/saving-nested-objects-with-rails-backbone-js-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for/5234044#5234044)

I would suggest to override toJSON on the backbone model.

```
toJSON: function(){

  json = {car : this.attributes};
  return _.extend(json, {engine_attributes: this.get("engine").toJSON());

}
```

toJSON is called within the sync method just before sending data to the backend.