# why are model relationships a challenge in backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, nested-attributes

I've seen the answer regarding changing the toJSON function in backbone to create a nested model
[Saving nested objects with Rails, backbone.js, and accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226067/saving-nested-objects-with-rails-backbone-js-and-accepts-nested-attributes-for/5234044#5234044),

But I'm trying to understand why this works, and why it is any different than just creating

```
var book = new Book({title: 'my first book', chapters:[{chapter_title: 'first chapter'},{chapter_title: 'second chapter'}...]});
book.url ='books';
book.save();
```

I've been trying to save to rails using the manual method, but i can't save the chapters. I find this strange, as far as I can tell the json structure is there, so what does the 'to_JSON' change recommended for nested attributes do? Why is it necessary?

As backbone models don't need to have model attributes defined, will there be problems when a nested models is returned? Or will it just parse the entire json without issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Rails, but it seems to me that the benefit of overloading the `toJSON` function is that `chapters`, in this instance, could be a model, or a collection or something, and have the extra functionality of Backbone.js as opposed to just being a JSON object.